# Tags in question bodies

Tags: support, tags

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27483811/difference-between-marionette-events) I just saw something that I hadn't seen before and didn't know you could even do.  Using a `[Tag:xxx]` construct the author put actual tags in the question body in addition to those in the `Tag` section.

Is this something that is allowed (and that I am just ignorant?) or should it be discouraged?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is an explicit feature, so yes, it is allowed.

You can also refer to tags on Meta with `[meta-tag:...]`; this too is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The feature is especially useful here on Meta when discussing specific tags.

In this specific case, however, it is just noise and should be edited out. Like ***over-application bold and italics*** or using backticks for `emphasis`, it is still possible to use a feature *wrong*. I've edited the post to remove the tags, replacing them with backticked keywords (as they *are* keywords in the API).

Comment: Oh to be so decisive.  I think I spent more time debating with myself about it being an issue or not (and then posting a question) than you did before editing that question!

Comment: @PeterM: I guess that just comes with experience. I've been editing posts on Stack Overflow for years now.

Comment: @PeterM FWIW this feature *mostly* exists for Meta and tag wikis. There are rarely ever circumstances for legitimate use inside a question or answer on the main site, and they usually just get edited out. It's pretty rare to even see them on main.

Comment: @animuson I used it [two years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12264751/256431) to note that I changed the tags on a question.

Comment: @MarkHurd: isn't that meta info? By now that add-on is way out of date and should just be removed. It could have been a comment back then instead.

Comment: @animuson Yes, it is out-of-date meta information, but it does still explain why that question got so many up votes :-(